# PHP date time object format to dmy error

Tags: php

When I run the following PHP code:

```
$this_year_start = strtotime(new DateTime("first day of this year")->format('d/m/Y'));
$this_year_end = strtotime(new DateTime("last day of this year")->format('d/m/Y'));
```

I get the following error:

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR) in /home/admin/data.php on line 164
```

I want to get the unix time of this year's start and this year's end. But this seems to have some issue format and making it convert to unix time.

Comment: Replace `new Datetime` with `date_create`, but I doubt that “first day of this year“ is accepted as argument.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to access the new created object inline you need to wrap them in parenthesis, like this:

```
$this_year_start = strtotime((new DateTime("first day of this year"))->format('d/m/Y'));
                             ^                                      ^
                             |                                      |
```

However this is not an option in older versions of PHP. The safe way to do it, is to create the object, assign it to a variable, then access those methods from the new created variable like:

```
$date = new DateTime("first day of this year");
$this_year_start = strtotime($date->format('d/m/Y'));
```

Answer (score 1):

`strtotime()` outputs a Unix timestamp - all you need is the string to convert.

You can use a textual format for the date with `strtotime()` such as "yesterday" or a date such as "march 15th 1991".

To get the current year, you know the start and end date, so you can simply put in "Jan 01" and "Dec 31" in the `strtotime()` string:

```
$this_year_start = strtotime('Jan 01');
$this_year_end = strtotime('Dec 31');
```

These two values will output:

> 1451624400
>
> 1483160400

For the end date, if you wanted to do the final second before the next year, you can add one day to it, less one second:

```
$this_year_end = strtotime("Dec 31") + (60 * 60 * 24) - 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

The year starts at 00:00.00 on 1st January and ends 23:59.59 on 31st December.

So for accuracy, as we need an answer as timestamp (that uses seconds), you should do something like this that applies times too:

```
// mktime(hour, minute, second, month, day, year)
$this_year_start = mktime(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, date('Y'));
$this_year_end = mktime(23, 59, 59, 12, 31, date('Y'));
```

Answer (score -1):

This works

```
$s = new DateTime("first day of this year");
$l = new DateTime("last day of this year");

echo 'First Day = ' . $s->format('d/m/Y'). PHP_EOL;
echo 'Last Day = ' . $l->format('d/m/Y'). PHP_EOL;
echo 'First Timestamp = ' . $s->getTimestamp(). PHP_EOL;
echo 'Last Timestamp  = ' . $l->getTimestamp(). PHP_EOL;
```

And outputs

```
First Day = 01/01/2016
Last Day = 31/12/2016
First Timestamp = 1451606400
Last Timestamp = 1483142400
```

Of course if you want to run it all together then this will generate your timestamps, notice the use of `()`

```
$this_year_start = (new DateTime("first day of this year"))->getTimestamp();
$this_year_end = (new DateTime("last day of this year"))->getTimestamp();
```

Comment: Random drive-by Down Vote or was there a reason

Comment: I didn't downvote, but he wants the timestamp, so you should replace `->format(...)` with `->getTimestamp()`.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois Yea just realised that, so I added the `->getTimestamp()`